# Laravel Not loading inner pages in Ubuntu -- Not found with 404

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ubuntu, laravel-4, routes

I have developed a laravel web application and running fine on live server, now I am trying to migrate that project to a local server,

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 with built-in php, apache, and MySQL.

When I pointed in a browser like a localhost/xxxxxxx/  (Login page) that worked finely, after entering values in the login form it showed the **404 Not Found error.**

How can I solve this, anybody please help?

Comment: I also had this problem deploying to a Digital Ocean Droplet running on Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 51, accepted):

This issue due to htaccess.

run

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Also change this in apache2.conf file located at /etc/apache2

```
nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Finally Restart Apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Working great. !!!!!

Comment: just a small tip, restart apache after applying changes in apache2.conf file with `sudo service apache2 restart` command